# bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have an ongoing problem with Bluetooth on Ubuntu 20.04
The Bluetooth is on, though the system shows that is off (see the image). I reinstalled all bluez drivers, restarted Bluetooth services, reinstalled the entire network manager, tried different dongles, but the problem persists.
Appreciate any help

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS5ui.png)

```
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ hciconfig -a                 
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:21 acl:0 sco:0 events:2 errors:0
    TX bytes:6 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 

➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ sudo hciconfig hci0 up   
Can't init device hci0: No such file or directory (2)
➜  ~ git:(master) ✗ rfkill list
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I updated the version it is 20.04

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.